# У меня есть блоки с запретными словами, мне надо чтобы например если чел написал запретное слово вОт ТаК то оно всеравно выполняло функцию

Tags: python, telebot, pycharm

```
 if message.text == 'Ракета на Донбас':
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                         '❌Ваше сообщение было удалено за ввод неверных слов! Повторные попытки приведут к блокировке вашего аккаунта!')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков лучше casefold: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold